# Modal not showing after database check

Tags: php, mysql, forms, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a registration form. The condition is, if the person already registered, then the same person cannot be registered anymore.

**What I Need**

I have the following php MySQL query which checks if there is an existing entry present

```html
  $duplicateCheckQuery = "SELECT * FROM registrationFormDetails WHERE email ='?' AND competition ='?'";
 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $duplicateCheckQuery)){
  echo "Duplicate check SQL statement failed";
 }else{
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss", $email, $competition);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($resultCheck>0){
   
   echo '<script>
   $("#exampleModal").modal("show")
   
   </script>';
         }else{
             //register
        }
      }
```

And I have the following modal codes which I copied from Bootstrap website

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I submit the form, I want the modal to appear. But it is not showing and instead it appears to be form is submitted. Does anyone know where am I getting wrong?

Comment: try to cover your js code with 
`$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
});`
mb js does not know that you have this form at time it is inited

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'?'`. They are unnecessary.

Comment: @Dharman Actually this was the actual problem which caused modal not to show. Because of that issue, `$resultCheck` always valuate as 0 and thus it never show modal window. I figured it out later part. Modal will show even without document.ready function as the other members suggested. I should give you the tick mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is as follows. In fact the initial code can work by removing '' marks around the ? mark in the prepared statement. Also you can place the script inside a `document.ready`

```html
  $duplicateCheckQuery = "SELECT * FROM registrationFormDetails WHERE email =? AND competition =?";
 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
 if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $duplicateCheckQuery)){
  echo "Duplicate check SQL statement failed";
 }else{
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss", $email, $competition);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($resultCheck>0){
   
   echo '<script>
   $("#exampleModal").modal("show")
   
   </script>';
         }else{
             //register
        }
      }
```

Then give modal codes

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The modal is getting initialized before the window fully get loaded, that's why it's not working. so you can change your code to this one, it works perfectly

```
echo '<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#exampleModal").modal("show")
        });
        </script>';
```